# In Tkinter, treeview: I have to move the newly added data under the specified child and the grandchild is not needed to repeat

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, parent-child

I tried the following code, I am now able to add the data as I need. But if I try to add data for an already existing child under the parent, it is not going under the specific child rather gets added at the end under the specified parent.
(after adding multiple children, if I enter data for one of the existing children then it should be added under this child of the parent.)
I tried the function to move it, but it did not work
for example:

```
tree.move(count, id, 0)
```

because the item already exists in the tree. so I am stuck at this point.

I am new, but I am trying my best to find it out.

Comment: I see error messages when I run your code and maybe this is your problem. First you could use `print()` to see values in variables to see what makes this problem. It is called `"print debuging"`. OR you should learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: @furas Sorry for not updating my code. I have worked on the problem and found a way to move the new data in the treeview. But this is not working after an increase in the number of data. I am stuck here

Comment: I don't understand why you use `count` to move item. `count` counts all elements in tree (for all parents and children) but you have to count only elements in matching parent and matching child. Maybe it would be simpler to keep information in normal dictionary and count number of elements in this dictionary `counts[parent_name][child_name] = number_of_elements`.

Comment: The child's name will not be added if it is previously present in the tree under the same parent. I am new to programming and searching in all resources to find a way. I am not able to understand your suggestion. Could you please give me an example?@furas

Comment: you don't have to add second child with the same name but increase number `number_of_elements` like `counts[parent_name][child_name] += 1` to see how many children with the same name you have and how to move element.

Comment: @furas I have no idea how to do this. I want to be able to enter the same child with different data for a, b, and c. and this data should display under the existing child. That is why I tried to move the data .

Comment: It works until it is under the same parent

Comment: it has to be more complex code then only `counts[parent_name][child_name] += 1` . It needs `if/else` to add new `parent` when it doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you for the idea, I will try my best to find a way  @furas